# How to use createdDateTime filter for identityRiskEvents graph api?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Right now I am using $url = "$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?" to query beta identityRiskEvents Graph api. I can loop thru '@odata.nextLink' and retrieve all event IDs. But looks like it can go up to $skip=5100 then it fails.

So I I am looking for a filter query with createdDateTime or any other property mentioned in this URL https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/identityriskevent

Trying to learn how these things work with powershell i.e. Invoke-WebRequest.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $filter query parameter to retrieve just a subset of a collection. Refer: [Use query parameter with Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter).

Comment: I do see createdDateTime attribute in the output and as per https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/identityriskevent URL, this attribute should be working for filtering but it is not working. I tried with below filter URLs both produce same result

Comment: $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?$filter=createdDateTime gt '2018-05-30T00:00:00Z'" & $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?$filter=createdDateTime lt '2018-05-30T00:00:00Z'"

Answer (score 0):

Panda in your case you need to use either escape character before the $filter or backtick that removes latest char and makes the dollar sign to be used as a character $ not as the variable starting mark...

If you want to pass $filter towards put a backtick before the dollar sign. As you need to pass that $ mark to the url and if you only put $filter the $ gets removed as it is the start of variable mark and if you don't have variable named $filter then you don't get any output as empty variable...

You can test by your self to write a text file and append there a dollar sign.
if you put it as `$filter it will go as $filter...

You need to remove the special meaning of that dollar and tell that it is to be handled as a static dollar without speciality.

Next are possible url filters that verified to work.

```
# Select 1 record:
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?`$top=1"

# Select by createdDateTime yyyy-MM-dd
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?`$filter=createdDateTime ge XXXX-XX-XX"

# Select by user account
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?`$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'username@domainsuffix'"

# Select by user and createdDateTime
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents?`$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'username@domainsuffix' and createdDateTime ge xxxx-xx-xx"
```